# Airflow Dynamic Task Mapping showing "No Data found" for Mapped Task

Tags: airflow, airflow-taskflow

I have airflow version 2.6.0 and python version 3.9.2.
I am following the official tutorial of [Dynamic Task Mapping](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.6.0/authoring-and-scheduling/dynamic-task-mapping.html) and I am using the example code for a dag:

```
from __future__ import annotations

from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task

with DAG(dag_id="example_dynamic_task_mapping", start_date=datetime(2022, 3, 4)) as dag:

    @task
    def add_one(x: int):
        return x + 1

    @task
    def sum_it(values):
        total = sum(values)
        print(f"Total was {total}")

    added_values = add_one.expand(x=[1, 2, 3])
    sum_it(added_values)
```

Even though the dag runs sucessfully, the interface shows "No Data Found", as it can be seen in
[this print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgkH5.png)
Why isn't it possible to see the output as it is shown in the tutorial?

I have tried updating the airflow to the current stable version (which is now 2.6.0) and tried to use the exact same code from the example, but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue on my local development environment where I do not have any login credentials. I have `AUTH_ROLE_PUBLIC = 'Admin'` in my webserver config.

There seems to be some issue where the API doesn't recognize this and you must be logged in with a user in order to see mapped tasks and logs. I just created an airflow admin user and login with that.